# Typescript: Is it possible to set types for specific object props and set specific type for the rest?

Tags: types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I would like to set specific type for 2 props and also specific type for the rest of props (I don't know exact number of them or their name... I will get the from the BE}

For example

```
type foo = {
boo: number
soo: string
[key: string]: Date
}
```

is something like this even possible ?

This works, but I need to set specific type for the rest:

```
type foo = {
boo: number
soo: string
[key: string]: any
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Omit` to remove properties, like this:

```js
type baseType = {
    boo:number;
    soo:string;
};
type restType = { [key: string]: Date };
type finalType = Omit<restType, keyof baseType> & baseType;
```